# How do I use sed to replace all lines between two matching patterns (on OSX BSD)

Tags: regex, macos, shell, sed, bsd

I would like to know how to:

- Replace all lines between two matching patterns (not include the patterns - exclusive). Please note that these will be on separate lines.
- Replace all lines between and including two matching patterns (inclusive). Please note that these will be on separate lines
  I have started the first, but its not producing the desired results (actaully no results so far). Please keep in mind that this is for **sed** on **Mac OSX (BSD)**. The pattern in this case is *two html comments* on separate lines.

My shell script looks like this:

```
REPLACEWITH="Replacement text here"
sed -i '' -e "s&\(<!--BeginNotes-->\).*\(<!--EndNotes-->\)&\1$REPLACEWITH\2&" /Users/BlaNameHere/builds/development/index.php
```

In the head of my index.php file is this excerpt:

```
<!--BeginNotes-->
    <!--asdasd-->
    <script type="application/javascript">var Jaop;</script>
<!--EndNotes-->
```

**example result a**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <!--BeginNotes-->
        Replacement text here
        <!--EndNotes-->
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

**example result b**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
Replacement text here
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you tied to sed, or will you allow other tools (e.g. awk)?

Comment: I wouldn't mind seeing an **awk** solution, at the moment I am most familiar with **sed**. I'd also like to stay true to the title.

Comment: What do you want the file to look like *after* the operation?

Comment: I will add to the above to show examples files a **a** and **b**

Answer (score 1):

A perl one-liner:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/(<!--BeginNotes-->).*(<!--EndNotes-->)/$1'"$REPLACEWITH"'$2/s' index.php
```

This uses the `-0777` option to read the entire file as a single string, which requires the `s` modifier on the `s///s` command

That one-liner is roughly equivalent to

```
perl -e '
    # read the file as a single string
    open $in, "<", "index.php";
    my $text;
    {
        local $/; 
        $text = <$in>;
    }
    close $in;

    # transform the string
    $text =~ s/(<!--BeginNotes-->).*(<!--EndNotes-->)/$1'"${REPLACEWITH}"'$2/s;

    # write out the new string
    open $out, ">", "index.php.tmp";
    print $out $text;
    close $out;

    # over-write the original file
    rename "index.php.tmp", "index.php"; 
'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n ":b
$ !{
   N
   b b
   }
$ {
   s|\(<!--BeginNotes-->\).*\(\n\)\([[:blank:]]*\)\(<!--EndNotes-->\)|\1\2\3${REPLACEWITH}\2\3\4|
   p
   }" /Users/BlaNameHere/builds/development/index.php
```

You need to load the file into the buffer becasue sed work line by line